# How to remove the shadow from the text of the svg and make it visible over it?

Tags: reactjs, svg, text, tailwind-css, shadow

This is my code in my React app and I find it difficult to make the text appear on the svg, and also want to remove the shadow from the text so that only the shape is having the shadow.

```
<div className='overflow-hidden'>
        <svg
          className='fill-green block m-auto'
          viewBox='0 0 500 150'
          preserveAspectRatio='none'
          xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
        >
          <g filter='url(#shadow)'>
            <path
              id='footer-shadow'
              className='stroke-none'
              d='M29.86,179.11 C100.86,200.36 200.94,60.48 450.84,180.09 L363.96,855.44 L0.00,190.00 Z'
            ></path>
            <text
              className='fill-modern-green text-sm'
              x='50%'
              y='100%'
              dominant-baseline='middle'
              text-anchor='middle'
            >
              All rights reserved.
            </text>
            <use xlinkHref='#footer-shadow'></use>
          </g>
          <filter id='shadow'>
            <feDropShadow
              dx='0'
              dy='0'
              stdDeviation='0.8'
              flood-color='black'
            />
          </filter>
        </svg>
      </div>
```

Comment: Try reemoving the filter from the first group `filter='url(#shadow)'`

Comment: It's removing the shadow of the svg too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stacking order isn't ideal.
The `<use>` element overlays you text – so swap the order and apply the drop shadow filter to your ` element.

```css
svg{
  width:50em;
  overflow:visible;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div className='overflow-hidden'>
  <svg className='fill-green block m-auto' viewBox='0 0 500 150' preserveAspectRatio='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
    <defs>
      <filter id='shadow'>
        <feDropShadow dx='0' dy='0' stdDeviation='2' flood-color='black' />
      </filter>
      <!-- path is only visible if referenced by <use> element -->
      <path id='footer-shadow' className='stroke-none' d='M29.86,179.11 C100.86,200.36 200.94,60.48 450.84,180.09 L363.96,855.44 L0.00,190.00 Z'></path>
    </defs>
    <g >
      <use href='#footer-shadow' filter='url(#shadow)'></use>
      <!-- The text is now in the foreground -->
      <text fill="#fff" className='fill-modern-green text-sm' x='50%' y='100%' dominant-baseline='middle' text-anchor='middle'>
        All rights reserved.
      </text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I also recommend to put your filters inside a **`<defs>` element at the beginning of your svg.** Some app frameworks (e.g flutter) struggle with defs placed after the elements these defs (e.g. filters, gradients etc.) are applied to.
So it's just a best practice for better compatibility.